# Get text and links contained inside "li" from a bs4.element.ResultSet in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
[<div class="rotation"><ol>
<li><a href="https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/">Program for array rotation</a><li></ol></div>]
```

In the above `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`, I want to extract the text `Program for array rotation` and the link `"https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/"`

How can I do that using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only a single link you like to get extracted you could use:

```
link = soup.select_one('li a[href]')['href']
text = soup.select_one('li a[href]').text
print(link, text)
```

But to go more generic, you could select all the `<a>` and than iterat the `ResultSet` with a `dict comprehension` to get unique `href` or `text` values, so also working for single items:

```
html = '''
<div class="rotation"><ol>
<li><a href="https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/">Program for array rotation1</a><li>
<li><a href="https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/">Program for array rotation2</a><li></ol></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

{a['href']:a.text for a in soup.select('div.rotation li a[href]')}
```

Out:

```
{'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/': 'Program for array rotation2'}
```

or with `list comprehension` to get all variations:

```
[{a['href']:a.text} for a in soup.select('div.rotation li a[href]')]
```

Out:

```
[{'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/': 'Program for array rotation1'},
{'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/': 'Program for array rotation2'}]
```